# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
public class MainJava {
private final String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbtest";
private static final String USER = "root";
private static final String PASS = "root";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection connection;
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} }
```

При попытке подключений к БД выводит ошибку:

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbtest

Перепробовал много способов решения данной проблемы, но ничего не помогло.
До этого пытался установить драйвера в файлы идеи, но безуспешно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А загружать-то драйвер кто будет?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class.forName(driverName);
    Connection connection;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Так тоже пробовал, но вылетает ClassNotFoundException к попытке добавить драйвер, в интернете пишут добавить jar файл драйверов в  проект, но я не совсем могу разобраться где именно это находится.

Comment: В итоге нашел решение: сначала сохранил драйвера куда нужно, подключил их, затем нашел вот такую строку jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydbtest?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC и после названия БД добавил useSSL=false и все прошло